# Android Jsoup login to get response

Tags: android, authentication, jsoup

I am trying to get a response for failure or success for a login for a mobile website.  Here is the part of my code.

**Edit**

---

```
public String login(String User, String Pass) throws Exception{
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(AmwayURL);
    String result = "nothing";
    try {
        // Add user name and password
        String username = User;
        String password = Pass;

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userpswd", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);

        result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
        }
        List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Local cookie: " + cookies.get(i));
        }

        // Consume response content
        //EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return result;
}
```

i do get a response and if i examine it i can see that i did perfomed the login but my question is how could use a programmatic way to find out if the login was a successful?

I cannot use a redirect code since that site stays on the same page.

Comment: Can you explain what problem are you experiencing? You can't login or you can login but cannot get a response?

Comment: i corrected my code and can get a response but i want to know a programmatic way to find out if the operation succeeded. for example how to know if a certain element is no longer there.

Comment: you need to parse the response using Jsoup, if selecting an element returns null, the element is not there

Comment: Can you explain how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Pass your response to a String and then just simply follow the official doc to parse !

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string

If you need to parse an specific element you can always do:

```
doc.select(your CSS query here searching a tag, element, class, id or even some atribute value)
```